# Java run-time type-value validator

Tags: java, apache-commons

I'm looking for a following Java run-time type-value validator.

for example I need something similar to following `validate(String type, String value)` method:

```
validate("String", "Hello, World!") -> returns true
validate("Integer", "Hello, World!") -> returns false
validate("Integer", "100") -> returns true
validate("Double", "Hello, World!") -> returns false
validate("Double", "43") -> returns true
validate("Double", "34.56") -> returns true
validate("Boolean", "true") -> returns true
validate("Boolean", "false") -> returns true
```

I can implement it by myself but I'm wondering if any already exists.. may be in Apache Commons library or somewhere else.

**UPDATED**

Is it possible to implement this task with Apache `AbstractFormatValidator` https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/AbstractFormatValidator.html ?

There are a number of sub-classes there, for example:

`IntegerValidator` https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/IntegerValidator.html

`LongValidator` https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/LongValidator.html
... and so on.

Is there any common interface for these classes that can solve problem that I have described in my question ?

Comment: This link http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29662/different-types-of-model-validation  may be helpful

Comment: There is a common base class: AbstractFormatValidator.

Comment: If you look at IntegerValidator#validate, you can see it delegates to parse in AbstractNumberValidator, so you can probably use this common parent directly